# A program that displays the characters which appeared least/most often

Tags: c

I've just written the code which is supposed to display the most/least (depending on a switch choice) appearing character. It has to work with standard input, that is from keyboard as well as with a text file. It's crucial for this program to show all char that appeared most often. For example in the input "abbcc" it should display b and c.
It runs, but it doesn't show characters. The question is: why?

Here's the code:

a) main

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int string;
    int allChars[256] = {0};
    while ( (string=getchar())!=EOF ) 
        allChars[string]++;
    if (argc < 2)
        mostOften(allChars);
    else {
        switch (argv[1][1]) {
        case 'm': case 'M':
            mostOften(allChars);
            break;
        case 'l': case 'L':
            leastOften(allChars);
            break;
        default:
            mostOften(allChars);
            break;
        } //switch
    } // else
} // main
```

b) sf.c

```
void mostOften(int *s) {
    int i, j;
    int max[256] = {0} ;
    int max_count = 1;
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (s[i]) {
            if (s[i] > max_count) {
                for (j=0; j<256; j++)
                    max[j]=0;
                max[i]=1;
                max_count = s[i];
            } // 2nd_if
            else if (s[i] == max_count)
                max[i]=1;
            else
                continue;
        } // 1st_if
    } //1st_for
    printf("The most appearing characters are: ");
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (max[i])
            putchar(s[i]);
    } //2nd_for
}

void leastOften(int *s) {
    int i, j;
    int min[256] = {0} ;
    int min_count = 1000;
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (s[i]) {
            if (s[i] < min_count) {
                for (j=0; j<256; j++)
                    min[j]=0;
                min[i]=1;
                min_count = s[i];
            } // 2nd_if
            else if (s[i] == min_count)
                min[i]=1;
        } // 1st_if
    } //1st_for
    printf("The least appearing characters are: ");
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (min[i])
            putchar(s[i]);
    } //2nd_for
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT1: deleted the mistake in the description
EDIT2: changed from putchar(min[i]), putchar(max[i]) to putchar(s[i])

Comment: Try stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger, and see what happens.

Comment: `putchar(min[i]);` and `putchar(max[i]);` doesn't look right...You are doing `putchar(1);` there.

Comment: hmm, I've changed it to the s[i], but it still doesn't work

Comment: But even thought putchar(1) is not correct here, it should still print something, shouldn't it? What I receive is only "The least appearing characters are:" and then nothing

Comment: Most characters with an low ASCII codes are non-printable characters. Either the terminal displays them as garbage values or it skips them silently.

Comment: There is a good chance the new line character or the space character are the most common. Try format printing the integer value e.g. `printf("%d\n", s[i]);` and find it in an ASCII table

Answer (score 0):

In your code for `mostOften`, `i` is the index to `s`, an that is the character itelf. So when you print out the list of characters that occur most often, you should print the character `i` instead of `max[i]`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (max[i]) putchar(i);
}
```

Another approach that doesn't require zeroing out the whole array is to make a contiguous list of characters. The length of the list is variable and kept in a separate variable, `nmax`. When you find a new maximum, just set the length of the array to zero. Don't worry about the array contents; `max` is only guaranteed to have sensible data up to `nmax`:

```
void mostOften(int *s)
{
    int max[256];        // list of characters
    int nmax = 0;        // actual length of max array

    int max_count = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (s[i] && s[i] >= max_count) {
            if (s[i] > max_count) nmax = 0;

            max[nmax++] = i;
            max_count = s[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nmax; i++) printf("'%c'\n", max[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
printf("The most appearing characters are: ");
for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if (max[i])
        putchar(s[i]);
} //2nd_for
```

to

```
printf("The most appearing characters are: ");
for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if (max[i])
        putchar(i);
} //2nd_for
```

since you generated `s[i]` as `s[<char-value>] = <num-occurances-of-value>`.